# Identify consecutive duplicates in R using accumulate

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, rolling-computation, accumulate

Let me share an example of what I'm trying to do, since the title may not be as clear as I'd like it to be.

```
data <- tibble(week=1:10,name=c(rep("Joe",10)),value=c(.9,.89,.99,.98,.87,.89,.93,.92,.98,.9),
               wanted = c("Yes","Skip","No","No","Yes","Skip","Yes","Skip","No","Yes"))

data <- data %>% mutate(my_attempt = case_when( week-lag(week)==1 & 
                                          value < .95 &
                                          lag(value) < .95 &
                                          lag(value,2) >= .95 &
                                          !is.na(lag(value,2))~ "Skip",
                                        week-lag(week)==1 & 
                                          value < .95 &
                                          lag(value) < .95 &
                                          is.na(lag(value,2))~ "Skip",
                                        value < .95 ~"Yes",
                                        TRUE ~ "No"))    

 #   week name  value wanted my_attempt
 #  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     
 #     1 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes       
 #     2 Joe    0.89 Skip   Skip      
 #     3 Joe    0.99 No     No        
 #     4 Joe    0.98 No     No        
 #     5 Joe    0.87 Yes    Yes       
 #     6 Joe    0.89 Skip   Skip      
 #     7 Joe    0.93 Yes    Yes       
 #     8 Joe    0.92 Skip   Yes       
 #     9 Joe    0.98 No     No        
 #    10 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes
```

I am trying to get the my_attempt column to produce the results of the wanted column. I want to identify rows when the value is less than a certain threshold, but there can't be two consecutive "yes" values. My attempt at it works until it sees 4 or more low values in a row. In my real data some weeks may be missing but that can be treated as a "No". For example, if week 6 was missing it would still be okay for week 7 to be "Yes" (I think the first line in my case when takes care of this). Is there a way to do this in R? It doesn't have to be consistent with dplyr but it would be nice if it's possible within tidyverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `purrr:accumulate()` here

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data%>%mutate(my_attempt = ifelse(week-lag(week, default = 0)==1 & 
                                          value < .95,
                                  'Yes', 'No')%>%
        accumulate(~ifelse(.x==.y & .y=='Yes', 'Skip', .y)))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
    week name  value wanted my_attempt
   <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     
 1     1 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes       
 2     2 Joe    0.89 Skip   Skip      
 3     3 Joe    0.99 No     No        
 4     4 Joe    0.98 No     No        
 5     5 Joe    0.87 Yes    Yes       
 6     6 Joe    0.89 Skip   Skip      
 7     7 Joe    0.93 Yes    Yes       
 8     8 Joe    0.92 Skip   Skip      
 9     9 Joe    0.98 No     No        
10    10 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes
```

Comment: Elegant use of `accumulate` here.

Comment: Learned from our friend @AnilGoyal

Comment: The question was a bit confusing for me, the op should have given more description on how one must calculate the desired output.

Comment: Yes our mutual friend is awesome.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you @AnoushiravanR. @GuedesBF, if `value` is lower than 0.95 in the example, I want `my_attempt` to return "Yes". But if the previous week already has "Yes" I want it to instead return "Skip"

Comment: @jtolleso, you should check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have added a base R solution and a not so different `tidyverse` alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I would have done it with rolling computation library like `slider` where missing data can be indexed well.  Showing you on modified data

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(week=c(1:5, 7:10),name=c(rep("Joe",9)),value=c(.9,.89,.99,.98,.87,.93,.92,.98,.9),
               wanted = c("Yes","Skip","No","No","Yes","Yes","Skip","No","Yes"))

data
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>    week name  value wanted
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1     1 Joe    0.9  Yes   
#> 2     2 Joe    0.89 Skip  
#> 3     3 Joe    0.99 No    
#> 4     4 Joe    0.98 No    
#> 5     5 Joe    0.87 Yes   
#> 6     7 Joe    0.93 Yes   
#> 7     8 Joe    0.92 Skip  
#> 8     9 Joe    0.98 No    
#> 9    10 Joe    0.9  Yes
library(slider)

data %>% group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(wanted2 = case_when(value < 0.95 & slide_index_lgl(.x = value, 
                                                            .i = week, 
                                                            .f = ~  any(.x < 0.95), 
                                                            .before = 1, 
                                                            .after = -1) ~ 'skip',
                             value < 0.95 ~ 'yes',
                             TRUE ~ 'no'))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   name [1]
#>    week name  value wanted wanted2
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1     1 Joe    0.9  Yes    yes    
#> 2     2 Joe    0.89 Skip   skip   
#> 3     3 Joe    0.99 No     no     
#> 4     4 Joe    0.98 No     no     
#> 5     5 Joe    0.87 Yes    yes    
#> 6     7 Joe    0.93 Yes    yes    
#> 7     8 Joe    0.92 Skip   skip   
#> 8     9 Joe    0.98 No     no     
#> 9    10 Joe    0.9  Yes    yes
```

---

Even it can be done without using `slider` i.e. in `dplyr` only

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(wanted2 = case_when(value < 0.95 & lag(value, default = 1) < 0.95 & week - 1 == lag(week, default = 0) ~ 'Skip',
                             value < 0.95 ~ 'Yes',
                             TRUE ~ 'No'))

#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   name [1]
#>    week name  value wanted wanted2
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1     1 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes    
#> 2     2 Joe    0.89 Skip   Skip   
#> 3     3 Joe    0.99 No     No     
#> 4     4 Joe    0.98 No     No     
#> 5     5 Joe    0.87 Yes    Yes    
#> 6     7 Joe    0.93 Yes    Yes    
#> 7     8 Joe    0.92 Skip   Skip   
#> 8     9 Joe    0.98 No     No     
#> 9    10 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(grp = cummax(week - lag(week, default = 0))) %>%
  group_by(name, grp) %>%
  mutate(my_attempt = ifelse(value < 0.95 & lag(value, default = 1) < 0.95, "Skip", 
                             ifelse(value < 0.95 & lag(value, default = 1) >= 0.95, 
                                    "Yes", "No")))

# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   name, grp [2]
   week name  value wanted   grp my_attempt
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     
1     1 Joe    0.9  Yes        1 Yes       
2     2 Joe    0.89 Skip       1 Skip      
3     3 Joe    0.99 No         1 No        
4     4 Joe    0.98 No         1 No        
5     5 Joe    0.87 Yes        1 Yes       
6     7 Joe    0.93 Yes        2 Yes       
7     8 Joe    0.92 Skip       2 Skip      
8     9 Joe    0.98 No         2 No        
9    10 Joe    0.9  Yes        2 Yes
```

And here is how you could do it with `base::Reduce` on a data set with missing week values. I first created a grouping `grp` based on the difference between week values and then `split` the data set based on the grouping variable. After that I applied our function on every chunk and bind the result with `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, cummax(abs(data$week - c(0, data$week[-nrow(data)]))), data$name), 
                      \(x){
                        x$my_attept <- Reduce(function(a, b) {
                          if(x$value[b] < 0.95 & a != "Yes") {
                            "Yes"
                          } else if(x$value[b] < 0.95 & a == "Yes") {
                            "Skip"
                          } else {
                            "No"
                          }
                        }, 2:nrow(x), init = ifelse(x$value[1] < 0.95, "Yes", "No"), accumulate = TRUE)
                        x
                      }))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
   week name  value wanted my_attept
* <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    
1     1 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes      
2     2 Joe    0.89 Skip   Skip     
3     3 Joe    0.99 No     No       
4     4 Joe    0.98 No     No       
5     5 Joe    0.87 Yes    Yes      
6     7 Joe    0.93 Yes    Yes      
7     8 Joe    0.92 Skip   Skip     
8     9 Joe    0.98 No     No       
9    10 Joe    0.9  Yes    Yes
```

In case you have missing weeks in your data like the modified data set here you can use the following solution. We first group weeks based on their consecutive values and then apply our solution on each group:

```
data %>%
  mutate(grp = cummax(week - lag(week, default = 0))) %>%
  group_by(name, grp) %>%
  mutate(my_attept = accumulate(value[-1], .init = ifelse(value[1] < 0.95, "Yes", "No"),
                                ~ if(.y < 0.95 & .x != "Yes") {
                                  "Yes"
                                } else if(.y < 0.95 & .x == "Yes") {
                                  "Skip"
                                } else {
                                  "No"
                                }))

# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   grp [2]
   week name  value wanted   grp my_attept
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 Joe    0.9  Yes        1 Yes      
2     2 Joe    0.89 Skip       1 Skip     
3     3 Joe    0.99 No         1 No       
4     4 Joe    0.98 No         1 No       
5     5 Joe    0.87 Yes        1 Yes      
6     7 Joe    0.93 Yes        2 Yes      
7     8 Joe    0.92 Skip       2 Skip     
8     9 Joe    0.98 No         2 No       
9    10 Joe    0.9  Yes        2 Yes
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), 
    name = c("Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", 
    "Joe", "Joe"), value = c(0.9, 0.89, 0.99, 0.98, 0.87, 0.93, 
    0.92, 0.98, 0.9), wanted = c("Yes", "Skip", "No", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Skip", "No", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: include `name` in group_by also dear friend